# Two rows two columns fluid page layout bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page which has a button. When that button is clicked I want the page to scroll down to another page which contains 4 squares (two rows and two columns) similar to [this page](http://y.co/) after clicking on explorer. I tried to do the 4 square thing with bootstrap using something like this:

```
<section id="my_section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">Top left image</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">Top right image</div>
        </div><!-- End of first row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">Bottom left image</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">Bottom right image</div>
        </div><!-- End of second row -->
 </div><!-- End of container -->
</section>
```

But for some reason, my 4 images do not properly take the whole content of the viewport (in other words, the two images at the bottom are not shown completely, I have to scroll down to see the rest of the content).

How do I make it so that my four images appear fully within the viewport of my browswer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you **have to** use Bootstrap classes? And more importantly, how do you want your images to be displayed on small, portrait devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout itself is easy to obtain. The question here is how do you want your images on different screen sizes and layouts? Would you like them cropped...

```css
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  height: 50vh;
}
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  background: transparent center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="my_section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:1/f00/fff)"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:3/444/999)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of first row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:1/ccc/f00)"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:2/999/369)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of second row -->
 </div><!-- End of container -->
</section>
```

...or contained?

```css
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  height: 50vh;
}
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  background: transparent center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="my_section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:1/f00/fff)"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:3/444/999)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of first row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:1/ccc/f00)"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:2/999/369)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of second row -->
 </div><!-- End of container -->
</section>
```

If you want to keep them side by side on all screen sizes, you need to replace `col-sm-6`s with `col-xs-6`s:

```css
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  height: 50vh;
}
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  background: transparent center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="my_section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:1/f00/fff)"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:3/444/999)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of first row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:1/ccc/f00)"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:2/999/369)"></div>
        </div><!-- End of second row -->
 </div><!-- End of container -->
</section>
```

The site you linked seems to use the cropped responsive version (1st one), with a small twist, to make the zoom effect. I added it as well, using only CSS and a minor change in markup:

```css
#my_section .row>[class^=col-] {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}
#my_section .row>[class^=col-]>div {
  background: transparent center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.01);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.01);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .42s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.55,.22), -webkit-transform 2.1s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .42s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.55,.22), -webkit-transform 2.1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 2.1s ease-out, opacity .42s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.55,.22);
  transition: transform 2.1s ease-out, opacity .42s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.55,.22), -webkit-transform 2.1s ease-out;
}
#my_section .row>[class^=col-]>div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.21);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.21);
  opacity: .444;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="my_section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:1/f00/fff)"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x2:3/444/999)"></div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End of first row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:1/ccc/f00)"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/800x1:2/999/369)"></div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End of second row -->
 </div><!-- End of container -->
</section>
```

---

As a side note, there isn't much need for Twitter Bootstrap classes in this layout. You can limit yourself to `.row` and have 4 direct children (or as many pairs as you'd like, just like the site you linked) using

- `{flex: 0 0 50%;}` on children and
- `{flex-wrap: wrap;}` on `.row`.

Of course you'd need some prefixes and some `@media` queries for browser support and responsiveness, but still manageable.

Don't be afraid to use <kbd>[flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)</kbd>. Today it has higher global support than <kbd>[box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)</kbd>, yet people are reluctant to use it as it's not *"fully supported"*.

From my point of view, the only `flexbox` feature that doesn't degrade nicely and would require `JavaScript` to reproduce in legacy browsers is <kbd>[order](http://caniuse.com/#search=order)</kbd>. Not a `flexbox` property in its own right, but commonly associated.
But we're talking *reordering*. Could not be done without js before.

Even Bootstrap is implementing `flexbox` in v4. Optional, but available.